# TypeScript gives error if instead of returning value throws Error

Tags: javascript, function, typescript, typescript-typings

I have this function:

```
public getObject(obj:IObjectsCommonJSON): ObjectsCommon {
    const id = obj.id;
    this.objectCollector.forEach( object => {
      if(object.getID() === id){
        return object;
      }
    });

    throw new Error(`Scene.getObject(). Object ${id} not found`); 
  }
```

And I get the following ts error:

> Not all code paths return a value.

That's true, because object.id must not be in objectCollector Array, in which case I throw an Error. How could I make this work? I've tried doing

> public getObject(obj:IObjectsCommonJSON): ObjectsCommon | void

But it does not work either

Comment: Try `return this.objectCollector.......`

Comment: return in forEach?

Comment: Why are you not using find() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is inside the callback to `forEach()`, not on the `getObject()` call.  Note that even though you are using an arrow function, it's still a function.  And the `return` inside the callback is returning from the arrow function, not from `getObject()`.  Note that for [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Basic_syntax), `x => {return y}` is equivalent to `x => y`.  There's no way to return from an outer function from inside an arrow function.

So this is your function:

```
object => {
  if(object.getID() === id){
    return object;
  }
}
```

And the compiler (if you've enabled `--noImplicitReturns`) notices that this function only sometimes returns a value, and so it complains.

Of course, `forEach()` doesn't care about the return value of its callback, and that wasn't your intent anyway. The fix is to do what others have suggested... use `find()` instead of `forEach()`: `... this.objectCollector.find(o => o.getID()===id) ...`  Or use a `for` loop:

```
for (let object of this.objectCollector) {
  if (object.getID() === id) {
    return object; // no callback, this returns from the getObject function.
  }
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @jcalz . Now it's clear!!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `find()` and add if check to throw the error.

```
public getObject(obj:IObjectsCommonJSON): ObjectsCommon {
  const id = obj.id;
  const item = this.objectCollector.find(object => object.getID() === id);
  if (!item) {
    throw new Error(`Scene.getObject(). Object ${id} not found`);
  }
  return item;
}
```